# I can not install db berkeley in my yocto project

Tags: database, yocto, recipe

I'm fairly new to Yocto and I can't install the db berkeley, in my custom image that I created with Yocto project.
I tried to install it with `IMAGE_INSTALL_append="db"` in my custom-image.bb (as I already did when I installed other recipes, like "rpm" or "iptables") but in this case, with the db berkeley did not work. I tried also to insert the "db" in the `conf/local.conf` file, but there's nothing to do. I don't understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is a 'bitbake db' working?  And what about 'bitbake-layers show-recipes db'?

Comment: The output of the command `bitbake-layers show-recipes db` is `=== Matching recipes: ===` `db:  meta                 1:5.3.28`

Comment: another one to test is 'bitbake -e YOUR_IMAGE > log'.  In the created log file (log) you can check if 'db' is indeed requested to install.

Comment: Ok, I checked the file "log", but there is not "interesting" info. Instead, I found the file `log.do_rootfs.16985` inside `build-dir/tmp/work/<MACHINE>/custom-image/1.0-r0/temp/run.do_rootfs.16985` and seems that the db was installed, (`Installed: db.armv7at2hf_neon 1:5.3.28-r1`). However when I run the command of db berkeley (like "db_load"), nothing to do; (db_load: command not found)

Comment: I also built the db-5.3.28-r1 with toaster and then I tried to install the rpm in my device, but nothing to do.

Comment: I'm more used to deb files, but you could try the same.  Try to read the content of the by Yocto generated rpm file.  Someting line 'dpkg --contents db-5.3.xxx.deb', but then for rpm.  There you could find that the expected commands/utilities are not distributed.

Comment: Thank you very much! @vermaete . So to recap, (for now) the solution it was to build the db berkeley with toaster and then install manually all the file .rpm. (Inside the file db-bin-5.3.28-r1.rpm there are all the db commands, like db_load)

Comment: it's not really *the* solution.  I'll hope you find the correct way with Yocto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should use oe-pkgdata-util to find out what you need if you aren't sure. In this case,

```
$ oe-pkgdata-util find-path *db_load
  db-bin: /usr/bin/db_load
```

So you just needed to use

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " db-bin"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! @anujm